# Double slashes in URL and rails route system

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my Rails application two URL such as

```
http://myurl/foo/bar
http://myurl/foo//bar
```

Are processed the same way. It's pretty smart from Rails to ignore the empty attributes contained between slashes but it becomes a problem when I link everything with the front-end Javascript framework ; my front-end routing system blows up because of it.

In my opinion, this should be understood as a problem in the URL by Rails because it seems more strict and logical.

Therefore, I would like to simply redirect the user to the homepage when the `routes.rb` detects a `//` within the path ; how is this possible ?

Thank you ;)

**EDIT :**

I tried this kind of things

```
match ':url' => redirect('/'), :constraints => { url: /\/+/ }, via: [:get, :post]
```

And it doesn't work, seems like the route file is read after rails manipulate the absolute URL first, or something like that ...

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing a regular expression the validates the route before it is passed to the specific controller to process the route. If the validation proves that the url is invalid it redirects to the home route

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to call a method or execute a REGEX for all routes directly in the `routes.rb` file ? Otherwise i must use `application_controller` but i don't find this very clean ...